# Can a `DocumentFormattingEditProvider` distinguish between a manual `Format Document` command and a `Format on Save` event?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm authoring a VSCode [Formatter Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices); it's little more than a class that extends `DocumentFormattingEditProvider` that I'm using to hook into VSCode's native `Format Document` and `Format On Save` functionality.

I'd like to provide some kind of 'ignore these specific files' behavior (to mirror the behavior of the external tool I'm using to generate edits) such that matching documents ignore all `Format on Save` requests. I think it would be useful to allow the tool to still run on matching documents when a user explicitly enters a `Format Document` command from the Command Palette. Doing so would require knowing what event generated the formatting request, and only ignoring some of them.

Is there there any way to detect the source of a format request, (`Format Document`, `Format on Save`, `Format on Paste`, etc.) either from within the body of [`provideDocumentFormattingEdits`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentFormattingEditProvider) or externally through another piece of the extension API?

I've not been able to find anything in the API documentation, or in the state of the running extension (when I drop a breakpoint inside my `provideDocumentFormattingEdits` method) that could provide that information.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.. nor does it seem like a good idea? What's the rationale for breaking the format on save behavior the user expects?

Comment: The eventually target would be to respect external configurations; in this case a `rustfmt.toml` that includes an `ignore = ["some", "files"]` member. My hope is to disable format-on-save for files matching the `ignore` set -- to mirror the behavior of running `rustfmt` against in the working tree -- but allow explicit formatting requests to edit the in-memory document.

Comment: Hm, I'd expect the explicit formatting request to do nothing in that case as well (this is how it works in the Haxe extension I help maintain, which has similar external configs for formatting). Presumably that's identical to the behavior of running `rustfmt` on that specific file via the command line.

Comment: And a thought: just because formatting was invoked via the "Format Document" command rather than "Format on Save", you can't really make any assumptions about whether it was "explicit" or not. Extensions can invoke that command programatically as well, I think there's one that implements a "Format Directory" that way (which seems like it should definitely respect the ignore config).

Comment: Ah, yeah, I hadn't considered the case of other extensions programmatically triggering reformatting via third-party extensions. That would likely be prohibitively complex to track.
I can't seem to +1 your comments (I guess I don't have enough points?) but thank you for the responses and perspective!